# How to quickly respond to Empathy message in Unity (Similar to Gnome-Shell)

Tags: unity, 11.10, empathy

I have seen the way you can respond to messages in a nice quick way in Gnome-Shell with a message window popping out from the bottom. How can this be applied in Unity for a window to pop up and just quickly click on it to respond to the user.

Comment: Why don't you use GNOME Shell instead of Unity?

Comment: Wouldn't that just defeat the purpose of the question?. What would had happened if I asked "How to play windows games on Linux" ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to accomplish this. It may be possible to write an application that replicates the functionality however.